# Can't read PDF downloaded from server

Tags: android, pdf, httpresponse

I'm downloading a PDF from my server.
The server send me a `HttpResponse` with the `InputStream` of file's body.
I'm able to write it into a file but, when I try to read it with a PDF reader, it tells me that the file might be corrupted.

I've also noticed that the size of the PDF downloaded directly from web service is twice the size of the PDF downloaded via my application.

The code I use to download and write the PDF file is this:

```
String fileName = //FILENAME + ".pdf";
        fileName = fileName.replaceAll("/", "_");
        String extPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        String folderName = //FOLDERNAME;

        try {
            File folder = new File(extPath, folderName);
            folder.mkdir();

            File pdfFile = new File(folder, fileName);
            pdfFile.createNewFile();

            URL url = new URL(downloadURL);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
            int bufferLength;
            while((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))>0 ){
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();

            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try {
                startActivity(pdfIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//otherStuff
```

Where I go wrong?

I've also noticed that inside the `Headers` of `HttpResponse` contains `Content-type:text/html`. It shoudld be something like `text/pdf`?

Comment: Are you able to open the file from outside the application(means from file explorer)?

Comment: Nope. Even opening outside the application tells me that is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Your Downloading code seems correct. Based on that and on your comment:

> I've also noticed that the size of the PDF downloaded directly from web service is twice the size of the PDF downloaded via my application."

I would suggest checking your URL. It appears that you might be downloading an html page instead of the pdf. To verify you are downloading correctly, change the download directory as follows:

```
//Default download directory
String extPath = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;
```

And check the directory (via the file system, e.g. mount the phone to your computer or a file manager app) for the downloaded content to verify it is a pdf.

Comment: Since I name the file ".pdf", it will always tell me that's a pdf

Comment: Correct ;) Let me clarify:
1. Try your code on 2 or 3 different URLs.
2. Try to open them with a standard PDF viewer (e.g. adobe reader) 
3. If your URL's pdf cannot open (saying its corrupted) while the other pdfs can, then you are downloading an HTML page.

Comment: Tried with different URLs, changing PDF viewwe (google viewer, dropbox viewer and adobe), but I can never open it

Comment: Could you please post your url here?

Comment: I'd rather prefer not to, since isn't my server. But is something like serverUrl/rest/myMethod?param1=value1

Comment: Ok. I didn't pay enough attention to your original question. Since you are referring to a web-service and not a typical website URL, the code to download a file should be different. I do not know how exactly since i haven't done it myself but as far as i know web services send a response in an enveloped mode. So in my last try to help out i would suggest:

1. Find a "download file from web-service" example in stack-overflow
2. Make sure your web-service implementation is correct. I can't help with that without knowing specifics.